# Neo4j within docker container stuck with 'cleaning up partially generated self-signed certificate'

Tags: docker, neo4j, ssl-certificate

I have mounted an /ssl drive as mentioned in the documentation and have placed inside it two files called neo4j.cert and neo4j.pem, I have assigned permissions to that folder as `775`.

The connection is done via a subdomain called plesk.subdomain.com and i have encrypted it with 'lets encrypt' I have then created symlinks to those certificates. fullchain.pem -> neo4j.cert and privkey.pem -> neo4j.key so that it will keep itself updated.

I have tried to run with the latest 3.5 as well as 3.4.17 and 4.0.0. I haven't had any luck getting this working again.

It has worked for a while but didn't have enabled renewal for my vps and upon restoring it hours later after suspension, nothing works again with the neo4j bit.